# Is there a way to construct a basis for a vector space $V$ from a basis for a dual space $V^*$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a $n$-dimensional vector space. And let $\{v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n\}$ be a basis for $V$.

Then we can make a dual basis $\{v_1^*, v_2^*, \ldots, v_n^*\}$ for a dual space $V^*$ as follows :
$ v_i^*(v_j) = \delta_{ij}. $

I have a question.

If $\{f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_n\}$ is a basis for a dual space $V^*$, then can we
construct a basis $\{w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_n\}$ for $V$ such that $w_i^* = f_i$ ?

Comment: Your question reduces to your known fact, using the canonical isomorphism between $V$ and $V^{**}$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Just define $w_i$ as the only solution of the system$$f_1(w)=0,\ f_2(w)=0, \ldots,\ f_{i-1}(w)=0,\ f_i(w)=1,\ f_{i+1}(w)=0,\ldots,\ f_n(w)=0.$$Then $w_i^*=f_i$.